# Why isn't my if statement functioning properly in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I was doing an experiment where a user enters a text and the program responds according to the condition. If the condition returns false, then the program prints the message "IDK". But when I ran it, I got the proper response and below it, I got the "IDK" message. What should I do to solve it?

My code :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("Hey.\n")

while 1:
    inp = input("Enter text - ")

    if "hey" in inp or "hello" in inp or "hi" in inp or "greetings" in inp:
        print("Greeting\n")

    if "sirwalterraleigh" in inp or "abrahamlincoln" in inp:
        print("History\n")

    else:
        print("IDK.")
```

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly There may very well  be a suitable duplicate for this but I don't think the one you linked is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `else` belongs to the previous `if`. In your code that's the history check. So you get the "IDK" each time the input isn't Lincoln or Raleigh. To print the "IDK" only when the input is neither greeting nor history, make only one `if` statements and add other branches as `elif`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("Hey.\n")

while 1:
    inp = input("Enter text - ")

    if "hey" in inp or "hello" in inp or "hi" in inp or "greetings" in inp:
        print("Greeting\n")

    elif "sirwalterraleigh" in inp or "abrahamlincoln" in inp:
        print("History\n")

    else:
        print("IDK.")
```